# PostgreSQL alternative to LATERAL

Tags: postgresql

I have a rather complicated query that I run in PostgreSQL database which performs a whole bunch of sums, calculations, etc.

One of the tables holds 3 different dates and based on their values, only one of them is picked. It is then used tens even hundreds of times in the calculations for that particular row. I can pick the correct date using a `CASE` statement which looks like this:

```
case 
when promotion_date is null and offboard_date is null then current_date::date
when promotion_date is null then offboard_date
else promotion_date end
```

As I said, this thing is used multiple times so copy and pasting it all over the query is rather insane. Instead, I wrote it as LATERAL join like this:

```
LEFT JOIN LATERAL ( SELECT (case 
    when promotion_date is null and offboard_date is null then current_date::date
    when promotion_date is null then offboard_date
    else promotion_date end) AS date
FROM promotions) AS promotionDate ON true
```

So now I can use `promotionDate.date` in the calculations which is much shorter and easy to read.

However, since that lateral is executed and calculated for each separate row and I also have quite a number of them, writing the query this way instead of copy/pasting the `CASE` statement all over the place significantly slows down the application. Is there a better / smarter way to achieve the same effect as the lateral but avoiding the huge copy/pastes when at the same time speed is not sacrificed?

Comment: How about `..., COALESCE(promotion_date, offboard_date, current_date) AS zdate` instead of the CASE expression?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your original query in a derived table, evaluate the CASE expression there, and use the result of that in the outer query

```
select ... other columns ...,
       calculated_date --<< this is now the result of the CASE expression
from (
   select .... , 
          case 
            when promotion_date is null and offboard_date is null then current_date::date
            when promotion_date is null then offboard_date
            else promotion_date 
          end as calculated_date
   from ... 
      join ...
   where
) as t
where calculated_date = ...;
```